# How to allocate Dynamic Memory to Device Pointer variable in C++ CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

all programmers.
I'm converting the existing C++ project to CUDA enhanced program.
I'm new to CUDA. So I'm learning during work.
I have to allocate memory to a dynamic struct member variable and the struct variable is allocated as device variable.

like this:

```
_cuda_params* dcuda_params;

cudaMalloc(&dcuda_params, sizeof(_cuda_params));

cudaMemcpy((void *)dcuda_params, (void*)cuda_params, sizeof(_cuda_params), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dcuda_params->DPht = (hashtb_entry *)malloc(c);  // c is size to allocate.
```

But during run time I get Exception 0xC0000022.
I also tried this:

```
cudaMalloc(&dcuda_params->DPht, c);
```

but the result is the same.
How can I handle this?

```
.h file
    typedef struct {
        int blocksPerGrid;
        int threadsPerBlock;
        uint64_t HASH_SIZE;
        hashtb_entry* DPht;
    } _cuda_params;

.cu file

void _GpuSearch(_cuda_params* cuda_params){
...
        _cuda_params* dcuda_params;
        cudaMalloc(&dcuda_params, sizeof(_cuda_params));
        cudaMemcpy((void *)dcuda_params, (void*)cuda_params, sizeof(_cuda_params), 
        cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        dcuda_params->DPht = (hashtb_entry *)malloc(c); //c: size to allocate.
...
}
```

Comment: The problem is the pointer in your struct

Comment: When you copy from host to device the content won’t be copied just the pointer itself.

Comment: I would create an array on device assign it to my struct on host and then pass the struct by value to the kernel.

Comment: I didn’t understand your question. You mean an array of struct?

Comment: Thank you, Oblivion. It's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing a device pointer, `dcuda_params->DPht = (hashtb_entry *)malloc(c)`; it is not allowed as the host doesn't have access to device memory.

The easy solution for your problem would be not using a pointer to an instance of your struct. You are not using an array of it anyway. So the function call changes to:

```
void _GpuSearch(_cuda_params cuda_params)
```

let's say `cuda_params` is not a pointer anymore you can simply do:

```
cudaMalloc(&cuda_params.DPht , sizeof(hashtb_entry));
```

from now on you are fine to pass `cuda_params` by **value** to the kernel. And if needed you copy from host to `cuda_params.DPht`.